# Can't create new projects nor items: Visual Studio 2010 dialog initialization exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Whenever I do Add>New Item, Add>New Project or File>New Project VS2010 is throwing a dialog initialization exception, preventing me from creating new projects or classes. Any idea on what could be going wrong?

Comment: Is this helpful? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/41f50aa4-c855-4214-be6d-4a2edef3c390

Answer (score 1):

Close all instances of Visual Studio 2010
    goto to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE" (depend of VS instalation directory)
    Run command: devenv.exe /resetuserdata -> wait until will be finihed
    Run Visual Studio